# Question regarding font selection

Tags: discussion

I am searching for many days answers regarding font selection and until this point I have found nothing, not only in our main site but generally. I asked a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274491/piece-of-code-regarding-languages-and-fonts) in the main site a few days earlier but while the answer was helpful I was confused even more while searching trying to understand it. As this is I believe an elementary question I am not really sure if it is a good fit for the main site so I want your opinion if I should post it there. My question is how to change the font in a document. What should I take care of? Should I take care of its math aspects? What about its sans aspects? Should I check if the font supports all the above? What are the correct code lines to insert the new font? Should I download it and save it somewhere particularly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Very nice of you to raise this issue. Unlike the general mantra in SO, in TeX-SX, elementary questions are also valuable for newcomers to TeX. Because these questions help to isolate the beginner confusions or similar problems. You might experience some *do your research* type weirdness potentially but with some patience it usually goes OK, if you can keep your cool with such users.

Having said that, you have to avoid the duplicate questions which is your part of the deal. A new font question in particular depends completely on the document class (which goes into `\documentclass{}` the packages you are trying to use (any font packages or are you trying to use a system font such as Verdana, Comic Sans, Ubuntu, Windows fonts and so on) and the compilation chain LuaTeX? XeLaTeX? and most importantly why you want to do this.

Often users ask a question about problem X to solve the problem Y which is called an XY problem. If you instead can describe problem X properly and avoid duplicates then fire your questions as many as you like.

Comment: You are absolutely right and that was one of the reasons I posted in meta as I thought that if there were some questions already, people would point them out. From my search there is no complete question posted but generally I am not pretty sure how to form the question itself so to get useful answers,